# How to create multiple line plots in pandas with columns having list values?

Tags: python, pandas

I was wondering how to plot the multiple line plots for the pandas dataframe with columns having list as elements.

For example, I can plot two plots using this data:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(color_codes=True)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'pig': [20, 18, 489, 675, 1776],
    'horse': [4, 25, 281, 600, 1900]},
    index=[1990, 1997, 2003, 2009, 2014])

df.plot.line()
```

But, How to plot the similar two plots for the following data?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'pig': [[20, 18, 489, 675, 1776],[20, 18, 489, 675, 1776]],
    'horse': [[14, 25, 271, 700, 1900],[14, 65, 381, 600, 1900]]},
    index=['A','B']
    )

print(df1)
                        pig                     horse
A  [20, 18, 489, 675, 1776]  [14, 25, 271, 700, 1900]
B  [20, 18, 489, 675, 1776]  [14, 65, 381, 600, 1900]
```

For each index A and B, I want x-axis = pig and y-axis=horse plot.
But I was unsure of how to do it. Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can loop over the indexes, it's not the best practice in Pandas to do that though, but it works for your case:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'pig': [[20, 18, 489, 675, 1776],[20, 18, 489, 675, 1776]],
    'horse': [[14, 25, 271, 700, 1900],[14, 65, 381, 600, 1900]]},
    index=['A','B']
    )

for idx in df1.index.values:
    plt.plot(df1['pig'].loc[idx], df1['horse'].loc[idx], label=idx)
plt.legend()    
plt.xlabel('Pig')
plt.ylabel('Horse')
plt.show()
```

[image]